# How to transform Json to Json using Jolt Specification?

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have `JSON`payload like this;

```
   [ {
      "Samples" : {
        "Load" : [ {
          "dataItemId" : "a5",
          "timestamp" : "2019-02-17T04:58:44.097Z",
          "name" : "Aload",
          "sequence" : "19",
          "subType" : null,
          "content" : null
        }, {
          "dataItemId" : "a7",
          "timestamp" : "2019-02-17T04:58:44.097Z",
          "name" : "AAA",
          "sequence" : "19",
          "subType" : null,
          "content" : null
        } ],
        "Angle" : [ {
          "dataItemId" : "a6",
          "timestamp" : "2019-02-17T04:58:44.097Z",
          "name" : "Aact",
          "sequence" : "20",
          "subType" : "ACTUAL",
          "content" : null
        } ]
      }
    } ]
```

I want to receive `JSON` like this;

```
{
      "Samples" : [
            {
              "tag_name": "Load",
              "dataItemId" : "a5",
              "timestamp" : "2019-02-17T04:58:44.097Z",
              "name" : "Aload",
              "sequence" : "19",
              "subType" : null,
              "content" : null
            }, {
              "tag_name": "Load",
              "dataItemId" : "a7",
              "timestamp" : "2019-02-17T04:58:44.097Z",
              "name" : "AAA",
              "sequence" : "19",
              "subType" : null,
              "content" : null
            }, {
              "tag_name": "Angle",
              "dataItemId" : "a6",
              "timestamp" : "2019-02-17T04:58:44.097Z",
              "name" : "Aact",
              "sequence" : "20",
              "subType" : "ACTUAL",
              "content" : null
            }
      ]
}
```

In my scenario, I must convert each json data defined above. I receive **500 JSON data per second**. How can I do this using `Jolt Specification`? Do Jolt Specification **fast**? Do it **suitable** for streaming? Or Should I write my **own script** for this?

Comment: `fast` comparing to what? `500 JSON per second` just increase the count of threads for this processor. `suitable for streaming`: [jolt consumes and produces "hydrated" JSON - in-memory tree of Maps, Arrays, etc](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt). ihmo: whatever you write would be comparable to jolt.

Comment: Is your JSON payload always an array with a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This spec works if your payload is an array with a single object:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Samples": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$1": "Samples.&2[#2].tag_name",
              "*": "Samples.&2[#2].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Samples": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Samples[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Otherwise you might need to split the array, do the transform on each element, then use MergeContent or MergeRecord to get them back together. Alternatively you could use JoltTransformRecord which applies the spec to each element/record in the array, the spec would just need to changed to remove the initial `*` section in the first `shift` operation.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect for me. Jolt specification generally a little hard  for me. I don't understand that how it works actually.